# Oracle Integration Cloud: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/sendmail returned a response status of 403 Forbidden

Tags: email, outlook, adapter, integration, icalendar

Tried configuring MS outlook adapter in Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC) Env.
The connection was successful. But when testing the complete implementation getting below error.

https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/sendmail returned a response status of 403 Forbidden

```
"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."

<genericRestFault><errorCode>403</errorCode><errorPath><![CDATA[POST https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/sendmail returned a response status of 403 Forbidden]]></errorPath><instance><![CDATA[{"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}}]]></instance></genericRestFault>
:Application Error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am successfully able to test the OIC Microsoft Outlook adapter to send email with attachment.When you configure the Adapter,please make sure that you have correctly set the followings.

Client Id:
Client Secret:
Scope: https://outlook.office.com/mail.send offline_access

Comment: I have provided scope as Mail.ReadWrite , I changed to mail.send it is working.